# How can I e-mail the content of a view to myself with Rules?

Tags: views, rules

I'm using Drupal 7, Views 3.5, and Rules 2.2.  I have a view that provides a page accessible only to admin users on my site, and once a week I would like to e-mail the content of that page to myself.

I know how to use Rules Scheduler to set this action up to occur weekly.  What I don't know is how to get the page provided by the view as a value that can be input into the body of the e-mail sent via Rules.

If it was a node, I could use `Fetch entity` to pull it in by ID, but since it's provided by a view, there is no such ID (that I know of) to speak of...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php code in the body of emails sent using Rules, so ultimately anything can be included. The easiest method, however, would be to use the [Insert View](http://drupal.org/project/insert_view) module.

Comment: Info on using PHP: http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/embed-drupal-views-using-php